# Drop down menu not working in Webview

Tags: android, css

My 3 dropdown menu's are working fine on this website meaning they appear on top of the images below the menu's           http://readautism.atwebpages.com
When I convert to an Android app in Webview, the menus go under the images instead of on top.  Any way to fix this.
Here is the html code relating to the dropdown menus. Let me know if other code is needed.  Thanks so much!!

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Filter</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="text-muted">Type</span>
                        <strong class="selection">All</strong>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu js-select-menu js-filter">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="all">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-sports">Sports</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-food">Food</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-clothing">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-animal">Animal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-body">Body</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".type-various">Various</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="text-muted">Letter</span>
                        <strong class="selection">All</strong>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu js-select-menu js-filter">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="all">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-a">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-b">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-c">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-d">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-e">E</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-f">F</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-g">G</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-h">H</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-i">I</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-j">J</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-k">K</a></li>                        
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-l">L</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-m">M</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-n">N</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-o">O</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-p">P</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-q">Q</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-r">R</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-s">S</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-t">T</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-u">U</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-v">V</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-w">W</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-x">X</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-y">Y</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".letter-z">Z</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="text-muted">Number</span>
                        <strong class="selection">All</strong>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu js-select-menu js-filter">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="all">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-2">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-3">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-4">4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-5">5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-6">6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-7">7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".number-8">>8</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sort</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="text-muted">Sort</span>
                    <strong class="selection">Name</strong>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu js-select-menu js-sort">
                    <li><a href="#" data-sort="name">Name</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-sort="letters">Letters</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-sort="activity">Activity</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right stats js-filter" data-filter-group="medium">
         <li>
                    <a href="#" data-filter=".medium-service">
                        <strong class="stat-count">0</strong>
                        <span class="stat-type">Words</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-filter=".medium-post">
                        <strong class="stat-count">0</strong>
                        <span class="stat-type">Articles</span>
                    </a>
                </li> 
            </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->      
</nav>   
<center>
<div class="container">
    <div class="isotope row">
        <?php

$conn=new mysqli("fdb13.awardspace.net","1778576_vibajajo","vincer64","1778576_vibajajo") or die ('cannot open database');

$sql='SELECT Criteria, Images, name, letters, activity FROM Persons LIMIT 100';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      

    $Criteria = $row['Criteria'];
    $Images = $row['Images']; 
    $name =$row['name'];
    $letters =$row['letters'];
    $activity =$row['activity'];

    echo "<div class=$Criteria>";
    echo "<img class=$Images>";
    echo "<h3 class='name'>$name</h3>";
    echo "<span class='letters'>$letters<span>";
    echo "<span class='activity'>$activity<span></div>";        

            };
 ?>

    </div>
</div></center>
    </body>

CSS
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
```

Comment: Hi,  Where do  I find the mobile nav dropdown height:auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that on the mobile nav dropdown you have set the height to **height: auto**. Change it to a fixed height, I set "height: 500px" and it worked fine ! I would explain why this has happened but I do not understand why it has done this... maybe, because the dropdowns height is not a child of the nav in some way.

**Edit:**

You could also add "overflow-y: scroll;" to the nav element and keep the "height: auto;".

Comment: Where are you seeing this mobile nav dropdown?  I can't find it.  Thanks

Comment: The nav element that you have placed in your file e.g. <nav></nav>

Comment: So I changed it to this but now the dropdown doesn't open at all?.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: 600px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }

Comment: Instead of adding the changes to the nav element, add the changes to this class only ".collapse navbar-collapse".

Comment: Changed it to this but still not working        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" "Height=600px">